# How to use Redux-toolkit "createAsyncThunk" in typescript based react class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am not understanding the proper way to use createAsyncThunk with class component. Can anyone give an example to call some api to render the fetch data in some component.

Comment: `createAsyncThunk` returns an action creator function -- a function that you can pass as an argument to `dispatch`.  Whether you are using class or function components doesn't matter.  In a class component you would access `dispatch` through `connect`: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch